# Thymeleaf Element Model processing

Tags: java, spring, model, thymeleaf, extending

How do I properly process HTML tag and its body in my own Element Model Processor? For example, I have the following HTML structure:

```
<my:form id="some_id">
    <my:input type="text" name="input-1"/>
    <my:input type="number" name="input-2"/>
</my:form>
```

I would like to alter both the wrapping `my:form` tag by adding some generated attribute so that output would look something like `<form id="some_id" other-attr="_generated_value_">...</form>` and process each of the inner `my:input` by adding an attribute with form id to each of those inputs (and generally process those tags as they should be), e.g. `<input type="text" name="input-1" id="generated_1" form-id="some_id">`. Normally `my:input` is processed by my `AbstractAttributeTagProcessor` extension.

As of now I have extended the `AbstractElementModelProcessor` creating the processor like this:

```
public class MyFormProcessor extends AbstractElementModelProcessor {

    private static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "form";
    private static final int PRECEDENCE = 1000;

    public MyFormProcessor( final String dialectPrefix ) {
        super(
                TemplateMode.HTML,
                dialectPrefix, // dialect prefix - 'my' in this case
                ELEMENT_NAME,
                true, // filter by element name prefix
                null,
                false,
                PRECEDENCE
        );
    }


    @Override
    protected void doProcess( ITemplateContext context,
                              IModel model,
                              IElementModelStructureHandler structureHandler ) {
        // what goes here?
    }
}
```

The processor is registered correctly and does turm the form and its body into a series of events, but I'm yet to figure out how to modify the `model` properly as I cannot find any modification methods on its elements.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your example work, I needed to make a change to your custom Thymeleaf input structure:

```html
<my:form id="some_id">
    <my:input type="text" name="input-1">
    <my:input type="number" name="input-2">
</my:form>
```

The difference is that I do not self-close the `<my:input>` tags (they end with `>` not with `/>`. This is so that they reflect the structure of the target "standalone" `<input>` elements, which are also not self-closing.

My approach processes the entire fragment of input HTML - so, if you also already have a separate processor for `<my:input>` tags, then I assume this would need to be a higher priority than that.

Here is the `doProcess()` method, with comments in the code:

```java
@Override
protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext context,
        IModel model,
        IElementModelStructureHandler structureHandler) {
    final IModelFactory modelFactory = context.getModelFactory();

    // first handle the form element:
    String formID = null;
    final ITemplateEvent formEvent = model.get(0);
    if (formEvent instanceof IOpenElementTag) {
        // retrieve the form's ID value:
        IOpenElementTag ele = (IOpenElementTag) formEvent;
        IAttribute attr = ele.getAttribute("id");
        formID = attr.getValue();
    }

    // build the attributes we want the form element to use:
    Map<String, String> formAttrs = new HashMap<>();
    formAttrs.put("id", formID);
    formAttrs.put("other-attr", "_generated_value_");
    // create the form element: 
    IOpenElementTag formOpen = modelFactory
            .createOpenElementTag("form", formAttrs,
                    AttributeValueQuotes.DOUBLE,
                    false);

    model.replace(0, formOpen);

    int idInt = 1; // used to increment ID values
    // the loop processes all of the elements inside the form's opening
    // and closing tags:
    for (int i = 1; i < model.size() - 1; i++) {
        final ITemplateEvent inputEvent = model.get(i);

        if (inputEvent instanceof IOpenElementTag) {
            IOpenElementTag ele = (IOpenElementTag) inputEvent;
            // we will add some more attributes here:
            Map<String, String> attrs = ele.getAttributeMap();
            attrs.put("form-id", formID);
            attrs.put("id", "generated_" + idInt++); // the "idInt++" is just a demo - use whatever sequence you want here

            IOpenElementTag openEle = modelFactory
                    .createOpenElementTag("input", attrs,
                            AttributeValueQuotes.DOUBLE,
                            false);
            model.replace(i, openEle);
        }
    }

}
```

The end-result HTML is as follows:

```html
<form other-attr="_generated_value_" id="some_id">
    <input type="text" name="input-1" form-id="some_id" id="generated_1">
    <input type="number" name="input-2" form-id="some_id" id="generated_2">
</form>
```

**Notes**

There may be more you could do to re-factor the code.

There are probably alternative (and maybe better) approaches to the one shown here. With Thymeleaf, there is often more than one way to do something.